# Substring() throws StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java

Tags: java, string, swt, substring

I have a function shortenDisplay(String longDisplay, String display) that trims the display via substring() method. However, if the display
passed to this method are both longer than expected, the substring method will
point to a negative index and cause the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. I need a way to get around this, I mean to make the code more cleaner and efficient so that it could handle lengthier String names. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here's my code -

```
    private String shortenDisplay(String longDisplay, String display) {
       final int displayLength = display.length();
       final int totalLength = longDisplay.length();
       final int numberOfCharsToRemove = totalLength - 36;         
       final int stop = displayLength - numberOfCharsToRemove;
       final String beginning = longDisplay.substring(0, stop); //this line throws an error        
       final int endStart = stop + numberOfCharsToRemove;
       final String end = longDisplay.substring(endStart);
       String shortenedDisplay = beginning + end;
       return shortenedDisplay;
    }
```

So for example if the parameters passed in are -

**longDisplay** - "Hey this is a string name display with a really Long length!!!!!!!!" (64 characters)

**display** - "Hey my name is string" (21 characters)

According to the 3rd line of code in the function *shortenDisplay* :
*int numberOfCharsToRemove* :  64 - 36 = 28 characters
*int stop* :  21 - 28 = -7 // Negative index

There is a specific reason for the existing code (requirements), so the code logic needs to remain the same but is there a way to get around this negative index and avoid **IndexOutOfBoundsException**?

Comment: What **exactly** is your requirement, i.e. what should the result of the method look like based on the input?

Comment: The requirement makes no sense. Why would you be required to shorten a string by 36 if it's less than that long to begin with? You can check for numberOfCharactersToRemove being too big, but then what do you do? Return a null string? Seems odd.

Comment: Eventually the method should be able to handle lengthier number of characters, for example more than 100 characters length String, but according to the current logic a negative index is passed into the substring() method, is there a way to handle this code logic in a more efficient way?

Comment: try to put a if else block like if (stop < 0) {....} else { //add the existing code}

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty fix to that specific line is to use `Math.max` to keep from falling into negative range.

`final String beginning = longDisplay.substring(0, Math.max(0, stop));`

Following that same reasoning, you'll want to protect the other call to `substring`.

`final String end = longDisplay.substring(Math.max(0, endStart));`

You have some magic numbers in the code that make it difficult to reason.  (Is 3 to account for an ellipsis?  What does 36 represent?).  I think rewriting the code to show the *intentions* better would be a huge win.